# Check if function is extension

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Given a `KFunction` how can I check if it's a extension function?

The only way I know is to check if `function.extensionReceiverParameter` returns `null`. Is there any other or a recommended way?

Comment: I don't know for sure but i think it's the only way. Kotlin reflection library is awkward in many aspects. e.g. You have to test whether the type represented by a KClass has a constructor or not to know whether this is an interface or a class. It lacks some extension properties to make it easy to learn and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the only way to check this is to use:
`function.extensionReceiverParameter`.

If it returns `null` it's not an extension function. If it returns a non-null value that function is a extension function